# Mark False if non matches exist

Tags: excel-formula

[image: example]

I'm trying to make a formula to find if there are "likes" for a person, that do NOT match a criteria, and return a true/false or yes/no value

So if Bob and James likes Apples and Bananas, Kathy only likes Apples. I want to be able to look up who likes Apples, and the part i am having trouble with, return if there are other things besides apples they like.

TL:DR I can't get the highlighted area to work.

I've tried xlookup and index/match but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Use COUNTIFS(): `=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,F2,B:B,$D$2),"No","Yes")`

Comment: I tried that, and it is just giving me all No's

Comment: then double check that you do not have spaces or other non printable characters that make it so they are not equal.

Comment: And they should all be NO, because they all have apples.  If you want to find who likes something other than apples then: `=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,F2,B:B,"<>"&$D$2),"Yes","No")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the *total* against the number of matches.  If they are different, then there are non-matches

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A, $F2, $B:$B, $D2) = COUNTIF($A:$A, $F2), "No", "Yes")
```